# caretList: Error in as.character(call_obj$na.action) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, r-caret, ensemble-learning

### caretList: Error in as.character(call_obj$na.action) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

```
models <- caretList(SalePrice~.-Id, data=training,na.action = na.exclude, methodList=c("glm","rpart","ridge"))
```

I am trying to caretList object in R but I am getting this error

`Error in as.character(call_obj$na.action) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'`

all the variables in my training dataset are numeric. Can that be a reason.

Please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Is "SalesPrice" also numeric? If it is, consider making it a factor. Perhaps also limit the number of levels for the factor variable (unlike numeric variable)

Answer (score 0):

removing na.action=na.exclude works for me. As the code for caretList shows na.action=na.omit is already defined in the function.

Comment: But what if you do have "na's" in your data and you don't want to exclude them. I get the same error when I include na.action=na.pass